# Ruby on Rails - Convert String to a DateTime action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am trying to convert a string like "6 months ago" and "3 days ago" to a date/datetime.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Chronic** gem provides such a feature. ([Github](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic), [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/gems/chronic))

It can parse rather complex statements. For example

- tomorrow
- thursday
- 7 hours ago
- last night
- fourteenth of june 2010 at eleven o'clock in the evening

can all be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

In rails, it can be done easily without other gems:

```
eval("3 days ago".gsub(" ","."))
# => Mon, 05 Aug 2013 13:31:06 UTC +00:00
```